# How to find the maximum value from a table in tableau and return a value from the other

Tags: function, filter, data-visualization, tableau-api

I'm a beginner in Tableau, it would be great if someone could help me with these queries.

I want to find the maximum value from the amount table and want to return the mode of payment that the maximum amount belongs to.

[image: Return mode of payment w.r.t the highest amount]

Similarly, if I need to find the sum of amounts of a particular mode, how do I do that?

[image: Sum of a particular mode (eg - UPI)]

Answer (score 0):

For first part use this T/F `CF` as filter for `TRUE`

```
SUM([AMOUNT]) = 
MAX(
{FIXED [MODE] : sum([Amount])}
)
```

OR if these aren'e aggregated already

```
[AMOUNT] = 
{FIXED [MODE] : MAX([Amount])}
```

For second one use `SUM([AMOUNT])` in view alongwith `Mode`.  In order to let me explain me better you have to upload some sample/fake data (not screenshot) that can be copied and worked upon in Tableau.  Good Luck.